# How can I download a calendar's .ics file using the Google Calendar API?

Tags: python, google-api, google-calendar-api

I need to programmatically download all of the .ics file from a user's Google Calendar. I wasn't able to find a way to do this using the Google Calendar v3 API but I may have missed something. Does anyone have any tips for how I can do this (in Python)? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a get request for the following feed:
https://www.google.com/calendar/ical/calendarID/public/basic.ics

The thread has more detail on how to https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-calendar-help-dataapi/bUFJLpoz59g

Comment: The first link seems to be broken now. Is there any replacement for it?

Answer (score 1):

Since I stumbled upon this from a google search and later found the answer,

use this link:

https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ical/CALENDAR-EMAILADDRESS-HERE/public/basic.ics

If anyone knows how to get from private (by providing api key or whatever) please comment :)

Answer (score -1):

For private calendars it's possible by using the private address

Example:
`https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ical/{PRIVATE ADRESS}/basic.ics`

See this link for more information about private address: [https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37648?hl=fr#zippy=%2Cadresse-privée](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37648?hl=fr#zippy=%2Cadresse-priv%C3%A9e)